# What's the best way to detect an incoming transaction with websockets and update balance?

Tags: transactions, metamask

What's the best way to detect an incoming transaction with web sockets and update balance?

Should it be done with polling?

Like for example - how would a web wallet do it? It's sitting idle - is it really polling the entire time?

If it's pooling all time, if you were on a sidechain like POA, you'd be checking every ~5 seconds, this doesn't seem efficient.

Is there any other way?

Comment: ~15 seconds (average block-time) makes more sense. But yes, you need to poll the blockchain, there is no other way (any "other way" would eventually be polling it).

Comment: checking every block (15 seconds) is just fine, even 5 seconds is still more than ok. A modern computer can execute billions of instructions per second (cpu wise). Other option is to use a contract wallet and then you can just subscribe to the events.